# how to create a project based on Durandal and dart

Tags: dart, durandal

i just started to learn [Google Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/)  using [Dart Editor](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/editor/) und i was curious to know if there are project or references using both Durandal and Dart something like  [DurandalJS template](http://www.asp.net/single-page-application/overview/templates/durandaljs-template). I am playing with Durandal since a while now and i really like it, is Durandal going to Announce something like DurandalDart?

NOTE: I AM TRYING NOT TO USE [AngularDart](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart)

**EDIT:** the answer from Garry Taylor is not what i am looking for there is no Dart in the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dart can interop with JavaScript but you won't get a good experience this way.

Dart has a lot of the functionality built in. (according to the listed frameworks on the DurandalJS link you provided)

I suggest you use `Dart` + `AngularDart` and forgot Durandal.

Comment: thank you for you help +1(upvote) but i am trying not to use AngularDart.

Comment: May I ask why? It's hard to make suggestions without more information what you try to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

You can create viewModels/Models/Services using Dart and convert over to JavaScript for pushing into a Durandal Project.

It can be nice to create the more complex ViewModels/Models using Dart. I plan on creating a project that does just that but it's not ready yet...

http://gpltaylor.github.io/DartTutorials/

https://github.com/gpltaylor/DartTutorials

Keep and eye on the project. I am currently plumbing in Grunt to get it to create the ViewModels/DataServices.